# Cannot install from phonegap build

Tags: phonegap-build

I create an app on Phonegap, as I always did.
I scan the QR code from my iPhone.
It tells me that it cannot open the page.
It used to work up to a month ago.
I also tried to open the page from the iPhone Safari browser, and then click on the "Install" button. I get the same error.
But, when I download the ipa to a folder on my PC, and then upload it to "https://www.diawi.com/" I can install it on my iPhone.
But I need to copy the link to the Safari.

Comment: Delete it and re upload

Comment: I did it many timed before and it didn't help.
But the problem was solved after I installed it from "diawi", so it probably something to do with the delete (as you say), but I had to install it from another site to fix it.